# How to generate a sentiment report?

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, pdf-generation, report

I have a web application (Java application) that does twitter sentiment analysis. Now my question would be, how can i generate a report that can print sentiment of a particular time? (It can be a pdf or a word)

I wasn't really sure of how to proceed. Please kindly advice.

What i have tried:

I was looking at: https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/

and JasperReports (Although this seems promising, I still haven't found a way to make this work)

Please advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't indicated what are the main problems you have run into with your Jasper and xdocreport.  You might also like to say what your sentiment print will include so that readers can advise on technologies.  [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) provides a Java or cloud solution which works from document templates and may be a simpler approach for your application.  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.